# .subscribe() is not triggering for GET request in Angularjs 4

Tags: javascript, angular, http

Just want to console log a response of `GET` request on page load.

Route localhost:4200/register is bound to `register.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { RegisterService } from './register.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-register',
    templateUrl: './register.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./register.component.css'],
    providers: [ RegisterService ]
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private registerService: RegisterService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("Start");
        this.registerService.getData()
            .subscribe((data: Response) => console.log(data));
        console.log("End");
    }
}
```

File `register.service.ts` which is included goes like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getData() {
        return this.http.get('https://userndot-a528b.firebaseio.com/code.json');
    }
}
```

When going to `/register`, console prints `Start` & `End` but not the response from the firebase dummy server. I've added `RegisterService`  in providers array in `app.module.ts` too. Compilation shows no error.

Comment: do you need to pass any header to firebase service? what are you getting in the console? try adding one error handler in the subscriber

Comment: Does the request go out? Try checking the Network tab under Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Request isn't triggered from the code. But if we hit the url directly/or via postman,it  prints the response.

Comment: no error either on console ?

Comment: Seems like working to me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sj8wzt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @echonax : it works for me too standalone, but not when implemented in project

Comment: @lazyrabbit How do you implement it? You know the console.log will be printed after "End" right? Not between "Start" and "End"

Comment: @echonax : Right, it should log after the end, but the problem is, it doesn't console any output except `start` & `end`

Comment: @lazyrabbit as David mentioned, do you see the request in F12 network tab?

Comment: it doesn't get fired, not request shows up in network

Comment: hey, noticed that if I move the code to app.component.ts, it works, but if I move it any route, then the problem persists.. what am I missing

Answer (score 0):

register.service.ts

```
getData() {
return this.http.get('https://userndot-a528b.firebaseio.com/code.json');
.map(res => res.json());
}
```

register.component.ts

```
this.registerService.getData()
.subscribe(data => {
console.log("data",data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below code . Added the `map` operator to get the json. you may have to use  `import 'rxjs/Rx';` if you have not done already.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getData() {
  return this.http.get('https://userndot-a528b.firebaseio.com/code.json')
 .map((res: Response)=> res.json());;
 }
}
```

Comment: @lazyrabbit do you have any CORS issue while connecting to the firebase from your local? that's the only reason i can think of as it is working for me too. Also you are able to connect it from postman.

Comment: I was wondering the same, what's the solution for that in Angular4 ..?

Comment: you have add request headers to allow CORS and make sure the CORS is enabled at the firebase end.

Comment: hey, check the @echonax 's comment on the question, it works for him.

Comment: hey, noticed that if I move the code to app.component.ts, it works, but if I move it any route, then the problem persists.. what am I missing

Comment: @lazyrabbit not sure what you mean by `move it any route` but you are supposed to call the service from the component only. `app.component` if you don't have any other child component

Comment: if I trigger the `this.http.get` ..in `ngOnInit` function in `app.component.ts` file, if works fine, but if I try to trigger `this.http.get` from /register route (`register.component.ts` is called for that) it doesn't get triggered. All the imports for modules are same in both.

Comment: @lazyrabbit can you post your app.module.ts where the services /component are added in array. Also the app.component.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155452/discussion-between-lazy-rabbit-and-niladri).

Answer (score 0):

Yoc can change you service as described by @Niladri or @Ravi Teja
or you can change this

```
this.registerService.getData()
        .subscribe((data: Response) => console.log(data));
```

to

```
this.registerService.getData()
            .subscribe((data) => console.log(data.json));
```

Comment: have you enable CORS on your project?

Comment: do we have to enable it separately for angular ?

Comment: no, you should enable it on backend side. But usually i set my header content request on angular side. Also have you tried to delete providers on @Component decorators? i notice that on my code, i've never used it